# What is the correct IF ELSE syntax in SQL server? - Preventing Duplications in a Column with SP

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have to prevent a column from duplicating so I made this Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].Agregar_Personal
    @nom varchar(20),
    @apll varchar(20),
    @tel int,
    @dep int,
    @sal float
AS
IF dbo.UnicoApellido(@apll) = 0
    INSERT INTO Personal (Nombre,Apellido,Telefono,Departamento,Salario)
    VALUES (@nom,@apll,@tel,@dep,@sal)  
    RETURN 0;
ELSE    
    RETURN 1;
```

(the function dbo.UnicoApellido returns 0 if the value is repeated in the table)

the issue here is that I'm getting an error in ELSE, saying that the syntax is wrong.
Can anyone tell me what is the error, or if there's another way to prevent duplications when performing an INSERT?

Comment: multiple statements in if or else statements require BEGIN and END blocks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/else-if-else-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IF` and `ELSE` need a `BEGIN` and `END`, thus your SQL would need to be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].Agregar_Personal
    @nom varchar(20),
    @apll varchar(20),
    @tel int,
    @dep int,
    @sal float
AS
    IF dbo.UnicoApellido(@apll) = 0 BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Personal (Nombre,Apellido,Telefono,Departamento,Salario)
        VALUES (@nom,@apll,@tel,@dep,@sal)  
        RETURN 0;
    END ELSE BEGIN
        RETURN 1;
    END
GO
```

This, however, doesn't stop someone inserting the data manually. You might want to consider adding a unique index to your table instead.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, I actually have my ID column, but i also need that one to be unique

Comment: @waroxx You can have more than one unique index in a table.